# How to calculate checksums when migrating existing files to Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, carrierwave, rails-activestorage

I'm migrating Carrierwave to Active Storage in the Rails 5.2.3 application with S3 as the file system. The problem is that some of my files are quite big (video files) and I can't simply download them to calculate the checksums.

For small files, I could probably use [`ETag`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html) ([fetched using the API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#etag-instance_method)). However, it won't work for bigger files. According to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html):

> If an object is created by either the Multipart Upload or Part Copy operation, the ETag is not an MD5 digest, regardless of the method of encryption.

Is there any fast-enough way to get the checksum of the file? Or do I need to monkey patch the [`ActiveStorage::Blob`'s `compute_checksum_in_chunks`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d5a2f7ec148726d7547e367d7a968e3b4be9b509/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb#L238-L246) method and all relevant code (like JavaScript lib etc)?

I would like to avoid overwriting Active Storage code because (1) it will be hard to maintain in the future and (2) S3 calculates ETag differently depending on the way how the file is/was uploaded. The only solution that might work is removing `NOT NULL` constraint from the blobs table and overwriting Active Storage to not raise the integrity exception when the checksum is missing. However, I'm not sure if this is a good idea (and maintainability is still relevant in this case).